# Social login extension for M1

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-social

Which extension of social login is the best for magento1.9. I am trying **oneall social login** extension but it's getting the error when I click on FB button or G+ button.

kindly suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this extension:

http://inchoo.net/magento/social-connect-magento-extension/

Its works for me.

Also you need to create facebook app from developer account also the google app from google developer account.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link

Paid: https://www.magestore.com/magento-social-login-extension.html

Free: http://www.magebuzz.com/social-login.html

Answer (score 0):

There are many free and paid extensions available in the market. Few of them are listed below:

**Free:**

- https://marketplace.magento.com/plumrocket-plumrocket-twitter-facebook-login.html
  (If only facebook and twitter login are enough) (I have tried it and it works flawlessly)
- http://inchoo.net/magento/social-connect-magento-extension/ (Tried 3 years back, but not sure that it will work for the latest version of Magento 1.9)
- http://www.magebuzz.com/social-login.html (Not tried)

**Paid:**
If none of the free works for you, then you can try paid solutions.

- https://marketplace.magento.com/webkul-social-connect.html
- https://marketplace.magento.com/etws-et-sociallogin.html
- https://marketplace.magento.com/softprodigy-softprodigy-sociallogin.html

Note that none of above paid extensions have any review on Magento Marketplace. But I would recommend webkul extension because they have good support for their paid extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Check this extension :

- [Free Social Login Extension](https://store.plumrocket.com/twitter-facebook-login-magento-extension.html)

Comment: This is only for twitter and Facebok, But i need G+ and FB.